# How to test correctly an observer in admin area?

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

I have to test an observer in adminhtml area on the event *sales_order_item_collection_load_before* (I declared it on adminhtml/events).

I found two different ways to test it, the first one loading the events of the adminhtml area, using:

```
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(
    Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, 
    Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS
);
```

The second one using my observer class directly, creating *Varien_Event_Observer* object  with sales/order_item_collection object.

The problem which I found with the first one is on load of the same collection in another method, because it given me problem on the session:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning:
Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the
current setting of session.save_path is correct
```

With the second one I had all green tests, but I don't know if is correct make it in this way.

I don't know what is the correct way and if I have to call tearDown with the first one to make something (and I don't know what) or I have to test the result without using the real observer as the second one. Could you suggest me the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to solve this?
In case not and this is still relevant to you, I would use PHPUnit (and EcomDev's PHPUnit for Magento extension) to create a mock of the sales item collection. Then you can use to mock's save() function to trigger your event observer. 
See also:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-about-mocking-with-phpunit--net-27252

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574331/ecomdev-phpunit-mock-magento-model-in-collection